# How do you solve the liebard riddle about the wind farm?

Tags: ramble-planet

When you find and talk to the treasure hunter in the wind farm, he gives you a riddle.

[image: "Climb the biggest tower. Find its bladed summit. Take fantastic power. Make all your foes plummet.]

I tried interacting with every single windmill in the place and nothing happened except one of them burned down.  What gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm Willy, the creator of Ramble Planet. I wouldn't take anything he says too seriously. Mostly it's just a bunch of misdirection.

However, the Liebard is important for something. His position on the surface rotates based on the minutes on the game's timer. If you manage to talk to him while he is in The Isles, he will give you a PART.

Comment: I was wondering why he kept moving around.  What does your time have to be at to catch him on the isles?